# Is a controller at a NFCT required to have an FAA physical? If so what class?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Is there a mandatory requirement for a Tower Controller working at a Non-Federal Control Tower (NFCT) to have a current FAA medical certificate?  Is a Class III sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would need a current medical certificate. Source is [here](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_90-93B.pdf) (page 4).

Although the above document is for NFCT, they do not mention which class is the minimum. However, I found at other places that for ATC, you do require Class II (sources are [here](http://www.ccbc.edu/airtrafficcontrolterminaldegree) and [here](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/general/classes/)).

> Second-Class - Commercial Pilot; Flight Engineer; Flight Navigator; or
>   Air Traffic Control Tower Operator. (Note: This category of air
>   traffic controller does not include FAA employee air traffic control
>   specialists).

This [flight school](http://www.richmorflightschool.com/) indicates the same:

> Applicants must:
>   possess a current, Class-2 medical certificate issued through an FAA certified examiner